# Infinite Loading Screen On IE 11 ( React )

Tags: javascript, windows, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a development server running and i am trying to access it from VM (Windows 10).

Basically Edge can launch the website and runs normally.
But IE 11 infinitely stucked with a "Loading..."

Did anyone experienced same problem?

The website build with react/redux.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using babel? if yes what is the version? and does it have target browser config set properly?

Comment: It seems more that its some library or some css stuff which is not supported.